# How to run a task from the aiogram python bot?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Meaning that it would work while performing other tasks.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


    

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def text(message: types.Message):
  if message.text == 'a':
    print(await periodic())
  if message.text == 'b':
    print('da')

async def periodic():
    for i in range(99999):
       pass
    return await 12


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

When the bot is written a, it runs the script, but when it is immediately written b, IT DOES not RESPOND. The meaning of the question is to understand how to start an asynchronous stream from a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [asyncio.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) to run task in asyncio apps.

Example:

```py
async def say_after(delay, message):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    await message.reply('С')


@dp.message_handler()
async def text_handler(message: Message):
    if message.text== 'A':
        await message.reply('B')

    elif message.text== 'B':
        asyncio.create_task(say_after(10, message))

    print('Message processing is done, but the task still working...')
```